# Different representations of classical momentum for 2-step optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, optimization

**This question is not talking about Nesterov's momentum so please do not think of it in that direction.**

According to page 2, Equations (1) and (2), of [On the importance of initialization and momentum in deep learning](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efritz/absps/momentum.pdf) Polyak's momentum (classical momentum) is defined as the following:

$v_{t+1}=\mu v_t -\epsilon \nabla f(\theta_t)\tag{1}$

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t + v_{t+1}\tag{2}$
where $ 0 \leq \mu <1$ and $\epsilon >0$.

Since $\epsilon >0$, dividing (1) by $-\epsilon$ and letting $w_{s+1} = \frac{v_{t+1}}{-\epsilon}$, one get the following:

$w_{t+1}=\mu w_t + \nabla f(\theta_t)\tag{3}$

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t -\epsilon w_{t+1}\tag{4}$

However, according to [Andrew Ng](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8fTYJPd3_I&t=395s&ab_channel=Deeplearning.ai) updates in momentum method can benefit the following process involving gradient:

$
S_{t+1} = \beta S_t+(1-\beta)\nabla f(\theta_t)\tag{5}
$

which is also known as exponential moving average process.

I am wondering how we can manipulate (1)-(2) or (3)-(4) to come up with a 2-step update one step of which is (5) and is equivalent to (1)-(2) or (3)-(4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Andrew Ng's video, the proposed scheme would be
\begin{align}
S_{t+1} ={}& \beta S_t+(1-\beta)\nabla f(\theta_t)\tag{5}\\
\theta_{t+1} ={}& \theta_t -\alpha S_{t+1}\tag{6}
\end{align}
Multiply (5) by $-\alpha$ and letting $v_t=-\alpha S_t$ yields
\begin{align}
v_{t+1} ={}& \beta v_t-\alpha(1-\beta)\nabla f(\theta_t)\tag{7}\\
\theta_{t+1} ={}& \theta_t + v_{t+1}\tag{8}
\end{align}
which is (1)-(2) with $\mu=\beta$ and $\epsilon=\alpha(1-\beta)$.